# Using Powershell to search for specific strings in the last x lines of very large log files

Tags: perl, powershell

I have a requirement that I have not found a solution or assistance for on the forums so far...

The issue: I monitor real time systems and these generate a number of very large log files that roll over on a daily basis, 1GB is not uncommon, and what I do is look through the (tail end of the) logs for known error conditions or other strings that I want to monitor for, which I may need to take action on.

As this sort of work is both time consuming and tedious, and easy for human error to miss issues within logs, I have been automating this log file monitoring. I utilise a product called Servers Alive to perform scheduled checks and I write scripts to monitor log files for occurrences of log entries that I am interested in looking for which may indicate problems with services, and I can than call other scripts to restart services if necessary to resolve the issue that has been encountered.

I have previously done the scripting for these log monitoring tasks using Perl and these scripts are very quick, but not necessarily the cleanest way to do this, I'm an admin rather that programmer so I don't have the developer methodologies or experience to rely on.

The Perl code snippet below shows that I 'open' a log file `$logfile`, and then 'seek' backwards from the end of the file for a given amount of data and then I search through the data from this point to the end of the file for the log entry I am interested in monitoring, in this example the log entry is "`No packet received from EISEC Client`"

In this example the log entry we are monitoring for indicates an issue with the EISEC service and a simple restart of the service normally resolves the issue, all of which I do automatically utilising Servers Alive as the scheduled check and alerting mechanism.

**Perl script function**

```
sub checkEisecSrvloggedon {

print "$logfile\n";

if (open (EISECSRV_LOGGEDON, $logfile)) {

    seek (EISECSRV_LOGGEDON, -40000, 2);

    $line = <EISECSRV_LOGGEDON>;

    $eisecsrvloggedon_ok = 0;

    while ($line = <EISECSRV_LOGGEDON>) {   

            if ($line =~/No packet received from EISEC Client/) {

                #increment counter
                ++$eisecsrvloggedon_ok; 

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to implement a solution for this using PowerShell if possible now that we have moved on to *Windows Server 2008 R2* and *Windows 7* clients, but I cannot find details of how I could efficiently do this, quickly and without any large memory overhead.

I have tried Get-Content based solutions but the need to read the whole logfile makes these type of solutions unusable as it takes far too long to query the logfile. I need to be able to check a number of these large logfile on a very regular basis, once every few minutes in some cases. I have seen tail type solutions that are great for tailing the end of the logs files, and these scripts are using `System.IO.File` methods. This does get the performance / speed I would like to achieve in my scripts, but I am not familiar enough with *PowerShell* to know how to use this methodology to get quickly to the end of a large logfile, and then be able to read backwards for a given amount of data and then search for the relevant strings in this log section.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use PowerShell 3.0 or newer, you can use a combination of the `get-content` and `select-string` commandlets to get the same functionality. Since version 3.0, `get-content` support a `-tail` option that only returns the last *n* lines of a file in an efficient way. Using this, you can reimplement the Perl script above with the following (searching in the last 1000 lines):

```
# Returns the number of occurrences
(get-content logfile.txt -Tail 1000 | select-string -pattern "No packet received from EISEC Client").Length
```

Comment: That sounds like the sort of option that may meet my requirment. I currently have PowerShell 2.0 on my systems, can I use PowerShell 3.0 on just a select number of machines within my site to utilise these PowerShell V3.0 functions in scripts running again machine with PowerShell V2.0?

Comment: I guess the machines that the script is supposed to run on must absolutely have PowerShell 3.0 installed. That being said, updating to 3.0 is probably very low-risk; as we all know, Microsoft is extremely pedantice about backwards compatibility.

Comment: I'll try installing PowerShell 3.0 on my admin client and try things out, I don't want to have to install on 20+ servers and 150+ clients if it not necessary. I'll post back when I have tried the above.

Comment: This does seem to be a reasonable soltion, i have tested and can read the search last 50000 lines for a specific string on a 400MB+ logfile in approx. 14 seconds. - I will need to try converting a perl script or 2 to see if they perform OK in a production environment.

Comment: This is looking like a pretty good match for my requirements - one additional little question. If I wanted to take the last minutes worth of data from the log, is there an easy way to acheive this? The log entries are not always consistant, but there are enties on most lines giving a time, such as the example here - (11:38:15 04-06612- SendOnSocket - Data sent to MDTSVR) - would it be possible to tail from a given point if I use the Get-Date function to get the currrent time and subtract a minute (or 2) from this point, ratyher than specifying the exact number of lines I want to tail?

Comment: Unfortunately, this would be significantly more difficult. As Get-Content only supports tailing by number of lines, the only way would be by tailing a sufficiently large number of lines first and afterwards filtering the lines in a second pass somehow. However, as this involve quite a lot of processing (extracting a date string from each line, converting it to a point in time, comparing it with the date limit), it probably wouldn't have any advantage over just outputting the last <n> lines. Should the need arise, you can just temporarily increase the number of analyzed lines.

Answer (score 2):

To seek backwards, [this contribution to the Poshcode repository](http://poshcode.org/87) appears to be a good match for your requirements:

```
# Name: Get-Tail.ps1
# Author: William Stacey
# Created: 02/22/2007
# Description: Gets the last N lines of a file. Does scan from end-of-file so works on large files. Also has a loop flag that prompts for refresh.

function Get-Tail([string]$path = $(throw "Path name must be specified."), [int]$count = 10, [bool]$loop = $false)
{
    if ( $count -lt 1 ) {$(throw "Count must be greater than 1.")}
    function get-last
    {
        $lineCount = 0
        $reader = new-object -typename System.IO.StreamReader -argumentlist $path, $true
        [long]$pos = $reader.BaseStream.Length - 1

        while($pos -gt 0)
        {
            $reader.BaseStream.Position = $pos
            if ($reader.BaseStream.ReadByte() -eq 10)
            {
                if($pos -eq $reader.BaseStream.Length - 1)
                {
                    $count++
                }
                $lineCount++
                if ($lineCount -ge $count) { break }
            }
            $pos--
        } 

        if ($lineCount -lt $count)
        {
            $reader.BaseStream.Position = 0
        }

        while($line = $reader.ReadLine())
        {
            $lines += ,$line
        }

        $reader.Close()
        $lines
    }

    while(1)
    {
        get-last
        if ( ! $loop ) { break }
        $in = read-host -prompt "Hit [Enter] to tail again or Ctrl-C to exit"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[PSCX](http://pscx.codeplex.com/) has a cmdlet named `Get-FileTail` which efficiently gets the last lines of a file and thus avoiding reading the complete file beforehand.

Comment: Getting the tail of a file is natively built into PowerShell as of version 3.0; see my answer.