# Use get-content to ge the latest 15 lines (entries) in the file?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Is it possible to get the 15 bottom lines from a file? I am talking about the ERRORLOG from SQL which has by default no file extension like .txt or something.

I thought about get-content and than filter the last entries.
I went for `get-help get-content`  and i get this nice information :

> Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, Get-Content can also get a
>   specified number of lines from the beginning or end of an item.

That's exactly what I want, but the get-help doesn't show me how it works. SO I NEED YOU ! *pointing*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the -Tail parameter:

```
get-content file.txt -Tail 15
```

Comment: thanks, i also just found out that i can use -last 15 as well :)

Comment: Is there also a possible solution for Powershell 2.0 ?

Comment: Yes, see my and Joey's answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624403/using-powershell-to-search-for-specific-strings-in-the-last-x-lines-of-very-larg/13625108#13625108)

Comment: thanks, for me also | Select-Object -last 15 worked out well.

Comment: Welcome, and that's a nice alternative. Also, don't forget the Get-Help command also has parameters and Get-Help Get-Content -full might have helped to guide you in the right direction.